# After inserted a data on a table in pgsql immediately when i am trying to fetch except last inserted row all data are returning

Tags: php, laravel

I am using react js and laravel 8. I have inserted a data on pgsql table through API and after inserted i have fetched all data from that table but I am able to get all rows except the last inserted row.
Even simple select query also not fetching all data immediately.

Firstly I have thought that it is react js state issue but when i have mailed the fetch result data then I have seen the same issue.

Here is my code

```
 $insertUserFavouriteID = Cms::insertUserFavouriteByAPI($userID,$dataset_graph_id); // Inserted a data on pgsql table and also returned the fetch data

        $sql = "SELECT id FROM favouritetable WHERE user_id = ".$userID;
        $result = App::getRows($sql);

        if($insertUserFavouriteID) {
            @mail("test.rp@gmail.com","My subject", json_encode($result));
            return $this->sendResponse($insertUserFavouriteID);
        } else {
            $error = array();
            $error['responseCode'] = '401';
            $error['message'] = "Error";
            return $this->sendError($error, 401);
        }
```

Can any one please help me why this is happing?

Comment: we will probably need some more information than you provided. try using postman to test the backend in isolation from the frontend. if you are certain that the question pertains just to the backend, please remove the reactjs tag from your question.

Comment: Ideally when posting that sort of question here, you should also post the simplest code possible that is able to reproduce the problem you are encountering.

Comment: @BetoFrega I have updated the description with my code also.

Comment: did you test it with postman?

Comment: Yes I have tested. I have fetched the data and mailed to my mail ID to check.
 $sql = "SELECT id FROM favouritetable WHERE user_id = ".$userID;
  $result = App::getRows($sql);
 @mail("test.rp@gmail.com","My subject", json_encode($result));

And this give me all rows except the last

Yes I have also tested with postman

Comment: Can you tell me what happens if you do this: Enter Record A and then Record B. Now query the table. Are you getting the record A?

Comment: I have just tested on postman again. But same result
1. 1st I have inserted a data A and fetched the from table and it is working
2. 2nd I have inserted another data B and when fetched all data from that table then only A returning but when i have checked the db then their were two data present A and B

Comment: I have checked that it is chache issue as i have used memcache.
Can you please tell me is their any way to remove cache before query run each time?